# Or condition in list comprehension

Tags: python, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

Is there a way to accomplish the below in a more concise way?  If i have a lot of values the for in condition my script will become very unreadable.

**Current Code**

```
import xlrd  
filename = r'H:\Book1.xls'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [sh1.row_values(row) for row in range(sh1.nrows) if 1 in sh1.row_values(row) or 9 in sh1.row_values(row) ]
print(data)
```

**Code Result**

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, '', 4.0, '', 6.0], ['', '', '', '', 9.0, '', '']]
```

**Desired Syntax**

```
data = [sh1.row_values(row) for row in range(sh1.nrows) if 1,9 in sh1.row_values(row)]
```

Also, would it be possible to pass in a list or some object that contains 1, 9, etc?

Comment: `if {1, 9} & set(sh1.row_values(row))` perhaps?

Comment: you can use `any`: `if any(i in sh1.row_values(row) for i in (1, 9))`

Comment: thanks AnthonySottile and njzk2

Comment: @Dot_Py did you just edit the tags?  Well, thats one way to get the copy editor badge lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a set:

```
if {1,9}.intersection(sh1.row_values(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function inside list comprehension. I'm adding generic code here. Can modify as required.

Example

```
def filter_foo(j, x):
   if j == x:
     return True
   else:
     return False

lst = [i for i in src_lst if filter_foo(i, x)]
```